Formula =A1:G6 Returns #VALUE! Error When Copying Table
I'm trying to copy a table from one part of my Excel sheet to another. If I manually copy the table (Ctrl+C) and paste it (Ctrl+V), everything works fine.
However, when I try to reference the table with a formula like:
=A1:G6
I get a #VALUE! error.
What I've Tried:

Checked that there are no merged cells in the source range.
Ensured that the destination range has enough space (no overlapping
data).
Tried using =A1 for a single cell, which works fine. But =A1:G6
results in the error.


What is the Excel version?

@rotabor My excel version is 2019

It looks like you need to select 6x7 range and enter =A1:G6 as the array formula. To do this hold Ctrl+Shift while pressing Enter.
Finaly, the formula should look like {=A1:G6}
